# For loop for counting the number of rows per table in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, row

I need to count the number of rows per table in a list containing several tables. I have written a loop but it cannot do what I desire:
Here is my dummy data:

```
obj1 <- list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"),side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", "GHT"), id = c("AA", "BB", "CC")) %>%  as.data.frame()
obj2 <- list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"), side = c("LEFT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("GOM", "LSM", "YYY"), id = c("ZZ", "DD", "FF")) %>%  as.data.frame()

x <- list(M = obj1, B = obj2)
```

And the for loop:

```
for (table in names(x)) {
  print(table)
print(nrow(table))  
}
```

I expect the output to be the number of rows per table (M = 3, B = 3) but it just yields NULL per table.
Could you please correct me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `x[[table]]` to index the elements in `x`

```
for (table in names(x)) {
    print(table)
    print(nrow(x[[table]]))
}
```

which gives

```
[1] "M"
[1] 3
[1] "B"
[1] 3
```

Otherwise, `table` is just the names in your list `x`, not the contents as it refers to.

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed I had tried this a bit differently:  `for (table in names(x)) {print(table) print(x$table)}`. I thoufht $ does the same job as [[]]. Could you please tell me why they act differently?

Comment: @Rara in `x$table`, the value of `table` is not further parsed to fetch `x$M` or `x$B`, but it treats `x$table` literally.

Comment: Not sure how relevant the printing loop-wise is, but if you just want an overview of all row counts and it's table name you can simply do `sapply(x, nrow)` which returns a named vector.